# Mouse forward/back buttons reversed

Tags: windows, mouse, firefox

For some reason the forward and back buttons on my mouse seem to have been swapped round. I'm inclined to blame the firefox 6 update for this, but see no way to put them back the way they were?

Comment: What model mouse is it? Also what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Trust. However I dont think its drive related. I just tested in explorer and internet explorer and its fine. It seems Firefox has just decided to swap them :(

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse buttons with this program: [X-Mouse Button Control](http://download.cnet.com/X-Mouse-Button-Control/3000-20432_4-75362562.html)